# Eliminate the entire row if bool key is false

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire, swifty-json

I have following response

```
"timeslots" : [
{
  "date" : "2019-09-10",
  "slots" : [
    {
      "end" : "10:30:00",
      "available" : false,
      "start" : "09:00:00",
      "timeslot_pk" : 78
    },
    {
      "end" : "13:00:00",
      "available" : false,
      "start" : "11:00:00",
      "timeslot_pk" : 79
    },
    {
      "end" : "16:00:00",
      "available" : false,
      "start" : "14:00:00",
      "timeslot_pk" : 80
    },
    {
      "end" : "18:30:00",
      "available" : true,
      "start" : "16:30:00",
      "timeslot_pk" : 81
    },
    {
      "end" : "21:00:00",
      "available" : true,
      "start" : "19:00:00",
      "timeslot_pk" : 82
    }
  ],
```

I want to eliminate the slots values if those contains "available" : false and load the tableview cells those contains onlyy available: true

Following is the API Call

```
if let slotArray = json["timeslots"][self.dayIndex ?? 0]["slots"].array{
                if !slotArray.isEmpty || slotArray != [] {
                    for slotJSON in slotArray {
                        let slot = Slots.parseSlots(slotJSON: slotJSON)
                        self.slots.append(slot)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }
                }
                else {
                    self.view.makeToast("No Slots Found!", duration: 3.0, position: .bottom)
                }
```

Comment: if no `Codable` inside `parseSlots` then you have a messy way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`filter(_:)`** on `self.slots` to get all the `slots` where `available = true`,

```
for slotJSON in slotArray {
    let slot = Slots.parseSlots(slotJSON: slotJSON)
    self.slots.append(slot)
}

self.slots = self.slots.filter({ $0.available })
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Reload the `tableView` only after all the `slots` are parsed and filtered. Reloading the `tableView` after every `slot` parsing will result in unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let end: String
    let available: Bool
    let start: String
    let timeslotPk: Int
}   

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase 
let value =  json["timeslots"][self.dayIndex ?? 0]["slots"]
let data = try!  value.rawData()
let res = try! decoder.decode([Root].self, from:data)
let filtered = res.filter { $0.available }
print(filtered)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just filter the array before creating the `Slots` instances

```
if let slotArray = json["timeslots"][self.dayIndex ?? 0]["slots"].array {
   let filteredSlots = slotArray.filter{$0["available"].bool == true } 
   self.slots = filteredSlots.map { Slots.parseSlots(slotJSON: $0) }
   self.tableView.reloadData()
} else {
   self.view.makeToast("No Slots Found!", duration: 3.0, position: .bottom)
}
```

Consider to drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of `Codable`.